# WebAPI core IFormFile always showing null

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have one front-end in angular 4, and one back-end in ASP.NET Core WebAPI, the functionality of them is, send data and an curriculum vitae of one people to one database which is SQL Server, but... always the IFormFile of method who catch the data and send file to the database is null.

I've already tried all type of solution that I found on the internet but none of them worked for me.

as response of the Post method i receive this exception

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.  
  NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  
  WebApplication.Controllers.CandidateController+<Post>d__4.MoveNext() in CandidateController.cs, line 60
```

Down here I pasted parts of the code of the project who do this.

github link for complete code:
[front-end code](https://github.com/whoisvinicios/form-curriculo)
[back-end code](https://github.com/whoisvinicios/web-API)

**HTML**

```
<form class="col-md-6 offset-md-3" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form)">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome completo" id="name"  name="name" ngModel />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" ngModel />
      <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">
        We'll never share your email with anyone else.
      </small>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="country" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Country</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="country" placeholder="Country" name="country" ngModel />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="state" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">State</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="state" placeholder="Estado" name="state" ngModel />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="city" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">City</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" placeholder="Cidade" name="city" ngModel />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="file" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Curriculum</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="file" id="file" name="file" ngModel />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container text-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Angular 4**

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
  const { file } = form.value;
  delete form.value.file;

  var data = new FormData();
  data.append('Candidates', JSON.stringify(form.value));
  data.append('file', file);

  console.log(form.value);
  console.log(file);

  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

  const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

  this.http.post("http://localhost:54392/api/candidates", data, options)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log("Foi");
      },
      error => {
        console.log("Não foi");
      });
}
```

**C#**

```
[HttpPost("candidates")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(IFormFile file)
{
    var json = HttpContext.Request.Form["Candidates"];      
    var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json));
    var candidate = new JsonSerializer().Deserialize<Candidate>(jsonTextReader);

    if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
        return BadRequest();

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await file.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
        candidate.CurriculumVitae = memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
    await dataBase.AddAsync(candidate);
    dataBase.SaveChanges();
    return Ok(candidate);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Upload images in Angular 4 without a plugin](http://www.bentedder.com/upload-images-angular-4-without-plugin/) provides a walkthrough of the process you're attempting to achieve. It uses `@ViewChild` to grab a reference to the file input in the DOM and then uses that when building up the `FormData`. In your scenario, this involves a few changes, as follows:

1. Replace `ngModel` on the file input in your HTML with `#file`. This creates a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ref-vars) that can be accessed inside your component when using `@ViewChild` in the next step.
2. Add `@ViewChild('file') fileInput;` to the component, above your constructor. This links the `#file` template reference variable to your component code.
3. Remove the following code from your component:

   ```
   const { file } = form.value;
   delete form.value.file;
   ```

   The `file` property will no longer exist at this point, so there's nothing to delete.
4. Replace `data.append('file', file);` with the following:

   ```
   let fileBrowser = this.fileInput.nativeElement;
   if (fileBrowser.files && fileBrowser.files[0]) {
       data.append("file", fileBrowser.files[0]);
   }
   ```

   This last block of code grabs a handle on the file and appends it to your `FormData`.

You can name the variables and template reference variable whatever you want. The only thing that needs to be specific is the string value `file` used in `data.append` *must* match the variable name used for your C# `IFormFile` variable.

As an aside, you can also remove your custom `Headers` and `RequestOptions` as setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` as a request header is doing nothing here. This header should be set on the response, by the server.

Answer (score 2):

I earlier had this issue, Got Fixed by removing.  ***'Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8'***

And Also you need to ensure you have same parameter send and received both at client and server

Answer (score 0):

Add the `[FromBody]` attribute.  You can read more here: [Binding formatted data from the request body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding#binding-formatted-data-from-the-request-body)

Change `public async Task<IActionResult> Post(IFormFile file)` to `public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] IFormFile file)`

Comment: Voted down. This results in a `HTTP 415` response. Got it working without any attribute.

Comment: Hi @LukePuplett - appreciate you taking the time to explain your down 

Comment: Thanks, I could be wrong, so leave the answer up. Your answer makes sense to me but didn't work in practice. Also, I think SO should make it mandatory to explain down votes. I assume they tried and people just entered low quality comments. One day there'll be a quality AI :)